# Best way to compress files

Tags: java, file, csv, zip

I am reading different chunks of data from DB and writing each chunk into CSV file and adding that entry to zip file. Here are my questions:

1. I am dealing with huge data, Is it advisable to open zip stream open in the beginning and closing at end of transaction? If I do so, will it hold all these data in RAM and cause any memory issues?
2. Will there be any advantage if I keep these csv files in hard drive and zipping it at the end of transaction? If so, what is the best way to do it in java?

Note: We are using Java 1.6 for our application.

Comment: Holding the zip stream open is unlikely to buffer (a lot) of content in memory, it will periodically flush the buffer, but you can also manually flush the buffer yourself.  As to weather there's an advantage will come down to your needs.  It might be better to process ALL the CSV files first and then compress them, as from a management point of view, it might be easier, it also means if one step fails, you don't end up with some corrupted and meaningless file...

Comment: And what does "huge" mean, anyway?

Comment: am dealing with millions of records

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new File system introduced  with Java 7

http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html

This allows you to handle a zip file like a file system and just copy or write your data directly into files inside the zip file. However the Path.toFile() method is not supported on a zip File system, so for all legacy code that required a File object, you need to create a temporary file and then copy it over.

For your application you could just use something like Files.newBufferedWriter(...) to write the file directly into the zip archive without having to worry about the specifics.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. we are using java 1.6 for our application. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no experience with zips under Java 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ZipOutputStream is wrapped around an outputstream that is not in memory (like a FileOutputStream). This will keep memory consumption to a minimum and you can basically write until your filesystem is full.

There is no advantage to first creating a csv file, then zipping it, write the csv line directly to the outputstream. This can easily be done with java 1.6

The only limitation you might run into if it gets **really** big is that java 1.6 does not support zip64 and as such you are limited to 4gb. At some point I backported the zip functionality of 1.7 to 1.6 to resolve this issue.